# How to save data to 2 databases in spring?

Tags: java, spring

I have Spring Boot project.
I have package finance.model where there are 3 models and repositories.
I have 2 DataBase config. First is remote database, second is local.
Now data from package is saving in remote data database

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "finance.repository",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "financeEntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "financeTransactionManager"
)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(FinanceDbConfig.FinanceDataSourceProperties.class)
@AllArgsConstructor
public class FinanceDbConfig
```

And data is saving from call in controller
I need that this data also is saving to my local repository

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "local.repository",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "localEntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "localTransactionManager"
)
public class localDbConfig
```

in both config there are line like

```
em.setPackagesToScan("model");
```

How can i save data to 2 databases?

Comment: look here https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases

Comment: there is saving different entities to different db, i need to save similar entity(object) to different db